# What is the correct way to indicate distribution of classes to binary artifacts in UML?

Tags: plugins, package, uml, components, class-diagram

I am trying to show the overall architecture of a plugin-/component-based system in UML. As a simple example for this question, I will show a main application that loads a plugin interface library (which defines the common interfaces for plugins), as well as two exemplary plugins (one of which comes with some internal details), as shown in the following UML class diagram<sup>1</sup>:

[image: only the class structure]

In my UML diagram, I would like to highlight how these classes (and the interface) are distributed to separate binaries<sup>2</sup>, in order to clarify what parts of the system can be replaced without recompilation.

Now, while I am aware UML provides quite some leeway and the main point of UML is not sticking to a rigid notation, but expressing information in a way to make it comprehensible, I still expect there to be a common practice for this scenario.

---

One straightforward way of representing the information that I had thought of is using a [UML component diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_diagram). [Wikipedia cites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_%28UML%29) the definition

> a modular part of a system, that encapsulates its content and whose manifestation is replaceable within its environment.

for a component. This seems to fit, given that what I want to show is precisely a replaceable component. Hence, by putting the above types into components, I arrive at this:

[image: class structure in a component diagram]

While this is comprehensible, I have slight doubts this is the acceptable notation, given that almost all resources (including the [aforementioned Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_%28UML%29)) on component diagrams I can find put a great emphasis on defining the required and provided interfaces. Formally, it looks like I should either add small rectangular ports or lollipop-shaped interfaces everywhere in the diagram where relationships connect elements across components. I do not quite like that prospect, as it sounds somewhat cumbersome to achieve, and more importantly, it would clutter the graphic without providing any additional information.

---

Alternatively, a [package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_%28UML%29) might be an acceptable notation. My purpose seems to match with what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_%28UML%29) describes in the second list in the respective article as

> When organizing component models, use packages to group the components according to ownership and/or reuse possibilities.

A package diagram would look as follows:

[image: using packages to represent assemblies]

On the other hand, I am a bit wary that using the package notation might create confusion with actual in-code packages (namespaces), which are actually *orthogonal* to assemblies. Indeed, [there are resources](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/package-diagrams.html) that interpret a UML package as a 1:1 mapping to Java packages, which is not what I am trying to convey (for the sake of argument, all depicted types might very well reside within the very same namespace, something like `MyGreatSystem.Plugins`).

---

The only other UML diagram type that could be somewhat suitable might be a [deployment diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deployment_diagram), but definitions such as the one from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node_%28UML%29) make it rather clear that a [node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node_%28UML%29) in such a diagram is either a physical machine, or an execution environment, both of which are clearly different from simply being in a separate binary.

---

One last alternative that I could think of is indicating the binary files by connecting the types with UML comments:

[image: using comments to indicate assemblies]

However, this seems more like a workaround to me, and I feel that the additional nodes and edges (rather than having the types *inside* the assemblies, where they actually are) makes the diagram *less* readable.

---

**What is the appropriate UML way to convey which types reside in which binaries in the finished product?**

<sup>1</sup>: No members for the classes and interfaces are shown here, as they are not relevant for the time being. This may or may not be the same in my final diagram, as the focus mostly does not lie on the complete internal class structure.

<sup>2</sup>: .NET assemblies in my case, but the question is equally valid for other environments/technologies.

Comment: Would someone mind to explain the downvote, please?

Comment: One never gets used to those down vote trolls...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a difference between the components, and the binaries that they are "manifested" in.

The **Component** is the *logical* grouping of behavior. The actual *physical* binary assembly is represented in UML as a manifesting **Artifact**.

The most dense notation for this can be found in the UML specificaton v 2.5 (beta) on figure 11.40 on page 221

[image: Dense Component Notation]

Make sure to use the correct relations between the component and the other elements.

There are a few alternate notations that can be used as well. From the same UML 2.5 specs:
[image]

Comment: Hmm, but what I want to show *is* the physical binary assembly. For the end-user, a physical binary assembly constitutes a component, because the end-user can replace and add assemblies, as long as they contain compatible types. The set of public types is the interface of the component. And those types, mostly classes, are exactly what I would like to show as the contents of each assembly, along with a relevant subset of their members. The Fig. 11.40 from the specification Beta 1 you are showing looks as if it is only a list of type names (?)

Comment: Physical binary assemblies are Artifacts, not Components. There are a few options in notation, but the model behind it stays the same.

Comment: Ok, so the substitutable compiled files that conform to a particular plugin interface so they can be replaced by the end-user are artifacts, not components. In that case, I'm still not sure what notation to use - I'm looking for some kind of a box (representing an assembly) that *contains* the relevant classes, to indicate that the respective physical assemblies physically *contain* those classes. At least in the [ptc/2013-09-05 version of the UML specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/Beta2/), it seems that the artifact element is used like the comments in my last example, i.e. ...

Comment: ... as free-floating nodes connected to the respective classes with edges. As I find this way of showing physical inclusion to be cluttering the diagram, less readable, and less intuitive than an *enclosing* box around the *enclosed* classes, I am somewhat reluctant to adopt such a notation. Am I missing something that you were referring to by "a few options in notation"?

Comment: I've added some of the alternate notations to the answer. The enclosing box notation such as Figure 11.43 only works well with a very limited number of classes. Personally I would use notations as shown in figure 19.10 and figure 11.42 as they clearly show the relations between the different elements.

Comment: Actually, I like Fig. 11.43 (and in my case, most, if not all components contain only <= 3 relevant classes, which would comply with the limited number of classes restriction). I am not sure what to do with the interface connectors yet; there is no way to literally show that a given interface type (such as `IPlugin` in my question) is *within* a component? As a matter of fact, in the depicted Fig. 11.43, how does a reader know which one of the two depicted classes, `OrderHeader` and `LineItem`, actually implements the provided interface `OrderEntry`?

Comment: You can show the relation between the classes and provides interfaces as well. There are some examples of that in the UML specs too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty fine with your first diagram vs. the one using packages. Components can well contain elements (as per UML spec it's composed of `PackageableElements`). For readability I would enlarge `Core Application` so the diamond lies completely inside. The third alternative is just that: an alternative. I'd prefer the first one.